# Two Comparison Functions Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, function, comparison

How i can use two comparasion mysql function ?

like this:

First

```
 GROUP BY 
      data_raport HAVING hours <= '8:00'
```

Secound

```
GROUP BY 
  data_raport HAVING hours > '8:00' but not higher than < 14
```

Third

```
GROUP BY 
  data_raport HAVING hours > '14:00' but not higher than < 24
```

Comment: With the `AND` keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like the `AND` keyword: 
`GROUP BY data_raport HAVING hours > '8:00' AND hours < '14:00'`

Or do you want to combine the second and the third grouping together, not completely sure!?

Comment: Thanks @luk2302 i was forget to put hours after and :"